# "As often as I can" vs. "As often as I can really"

Tags: meaning

Consider this conversation

> Question: "How do you often wear jeans?"
>
> Answer1: "As often as I can **really**."

I guess the answer is grammatically correct. I don't really understand the meaning of "really" here, though I understand the meaning and the usage of the adverb "really" in general.

What's the difference between that one and the following?

> Answer2: "As often as I can."

Does Answer1 convey more emphasis than Answer2?

Comment: It doesn't have any meaning, it's just a 'conversation filler'. The respondent doesn't have a definite answer like "At weekends and on holiday," so they use the meaningless _really_ to imply something like "Now I come to think about it, I suppose..."

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. So, Answer2 is as common as Answer1, and they mean the same thing in any situations, right?

Comment: It's not a question of which is 'more common'. Answer 2 is a possible answer to the question. The addition of _really_ is just a meaningless 'filler' that this particular speaker has chosen to use for the reason I explained above. Do not think of it as a significant word that you need to learn about.